# KeyStore certificate

Tags: java

I want to add a certificate to my JRE folder which is required to make a trusted HTPPS connection to a server. I imported the certificate to the target folder where it asked for just a password and it was done. Since it is still not effective, I want to remove it and add it back but I'm not able to figure out the name of the Keystore .

I tried listing the Keystore values using cmd
Keystore -list -v 
It is listing out my Keystore certificate detail with alias name, keystore type,provider etc but not the file name of keystore. I tried giving .keystore as default file name but it throws 'file doesn't exist' error.
 Please help me in finding out the filename of my keystore so that I can delete it and add newly.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin>keytool -list -v
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN
```

Your keystore contains 1 entry

> Alias name: mykey Creation date: Aug 1, 2019 Entry type:
>   trustedCertEntry

Need to find the keystore file name and delete it.

Comment: You don't need the name of the keystore. There is a default, and you don't need to delete it, and that's where the certificate is. If you want to delete the certificate, just use the delete option and provide the alias that is listed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the certificates you can just re-import them into a specific file and then use that file.

Example:
`keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"`

This will import the certificate.cer file into the keystore name "keystore.jks" and save the certificate under the alias "Alias".
Typically this will be your CA certificate that you want to put into the keystore for the site that you want to trust.

Then you can pass this truststore to the java application so that it is able to authenticate the server cert presented by the site/application that you want to connect to (assuming it is signed by the CA cert that you just imported).

**Note: Look at files ending `jks` in your jre8/bin directory to see if you are able to see files that you have created today. And that should be your file.**

To set the trust store start the java process with this `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/new/truststore and -Djava.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=...`